# How to use IOTA with a TTN network (of LoRa nodes)?

Tags: iota-network, node, internet-of-things

I am working in a project where I create a LoRa Gateway on [The Things Network](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/) (TTN). I want my nodes to work with IOTA. Is it possible to use IOTA with the TTN network?

Comment: What aspect of IOTA do you want to use?